# Compare (2) Select Results from (2) different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with an .ini file that inputs select results into MS Word (based on bookmarks) and all works seamlessly, however I am now trying to have a signature verification display text on a final document.

Here are the queries.

**Query #1 = **

```
select B.PERSON 
  from TV_ARRESULT A, 
       TV_BANKER B 
 where A."KEY" = 'abc123' 
   AND A.TEST_TYPE_CODE='ETSTWIT' 
   AND A.RESULT = B.NAME
```

RESULT = John Doe

**Query #2 =**

```
select WITNESSED_BY 
  from TV_ARRESULT t 
 where "KEY" = 'abc123' 
   AND TEST_TYPE_CODE='ETSTWIT'
```

RESULT = John Doe

I need to compare the result selects from these (2) queries, and then have my code perform a function based on the this.

Basically :

if B.PERSON = A.REVIEWER then do a function
or

if B.PERSON <> A.REVIEWER then display some kind of error text in MS Word

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need two queries? Since witnessed_by in query 2 is coming from a table used in Query 1, with the same filters, I figure you have all the information you need from the first query. Assuming of course that A.RESULT = B.NAME is satisfied for at least 1 record in TV_ARRESULT for all results. Otherwise you could have cases where Query 1 returns nothing, but query 2 does not.

```
select B.PERSON,
       case when b.person = a.WITNESSED_BY then 'Action 1'
            else 'Action 2'
        end as do_this_action
  from TV_ARRESULT A
 inner
  join TV_BANKER B 
 where A."KEY" = 'abc123' 
   and A.TEST_TYPE_CODE='ETSTWIT' 
   and A.RESULT = B.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and `COUNT` as follows:

```
select CASE WHEN COUNT(B.NAME) > 0
       THEN 'Some action'
       ELSE 'Error'
       END AS RESULT
  from TV_ARRESULT A
       LEFT JOIN TV_BANKER B 
       ON A.RESULT = B.NAME AND B.PERSON = A.WITNESSED_BY
 where A."KEY" = 'abc123' 
   AND A.TEST_TYPE_CODE='ETSTWIT';
```